# How can I implement the caesar cipher into python?

Tags: python, while-loop, nested-loops, caesar-cipher

I can't seem to get the cipher to work correctly.

I am trying to reset the value of j each time it enters the loop, but it just keeps getting stuck in an infinite loop. Furthermore, what shall I do to change each letter in a file to a specified letter?

```
import sys
file = sys.argv[1]

with open(file, 'r') as f:
    filedata = f.read()

old_string = filedata

alp = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
i = 0
j = 0
key = int(sys.argv[2])

while i < len(filedata):
    j = 0
    if filedata[i] != alp[j]:
        j+=1

    if filedata[i] == alp[j]:
        k = old_string.rfind(filedata[i])
        if i < (len(alp) - key):
            old_string = old_string[:k] + alp[j+key] + old_string[k+1:]
        else:
            old_string = old_string[:k] + alp[(j+key)%26] + old_string[k+1:]
    i += 1

with open(file, 'w') as f:
    f.write(old_string)
```

Comment: This shouldn't be an infinite loop, and it also isn't a nested loop; There's only one loop in your code, which will inevitably end regardless of input. The file read() and write(), though might be the reason this takes time.

Answer (score 1):

Your while loop doesn't look like pythonic.When you try to use complex things, it makes your code complicated. Try to use for in loop like this:

```
for symbol in filedata:
    if symbol.isalpha():
        actions..
```

And you don't need to use i and j index in it.

But if you want to use "while" loop, make this

```
while i < len(filedata):
    j = 0
    while j < len(alp):
        if filedata[i] != alp[j]:
            j+=1

        if filedata[i] == alp[j]:
            k = old_string.rfind(filedata[i])
            if i < (len(alp) - key):
                old_string = old_string[:k] + alp[j+key] + old_string[k+1:]
            else:
                old_string = old_string[:k] + alp[(j+key)%26] + old_string[k+1:]
            break
    i += 1
```

Try to use simple features, which there are a lot in Python

Comment: There's no solution to OP's problem in your answer. Also, this doesn't look like code of someone who's trying to over-complexify, rather like code of someone who is familiar with another language.

Comment: If he won't use i and j indexes in this case, it also can solve the problem

Comment: If you're trying to give him a direction, give him a lead for what the error is alongside the best practice

Comment: Like this now ?

Comment: That's better, you could have also just given him a lead. Upvoted :)

Comment: Thanks for giving me a lead)